# Add button in a tooltip

Tags: php, d3.js

Currently, I am using this for server monitoring :

> http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9692795

The problem is, I am not getting how to add buttons (start, stop) in a tooltip.

I have gone through `d3js` tooltip doc:

> http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html

But not able to do this. Can anyone help me please.

Current Code:

```
// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
            .on("click", click)
            // add tool tip for ps -eo pid,ppid,pcpu,size,comm,ruser,s
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                    div .html(
                        "PID: " + d.name + "<br/>" + 
                        "Command: " + d.COMMAND + "<br/>" +
                        "User: " + d.RUSER + "<br/>" +
                        "%CPU: " + d.CPU + "<br/>" +
                        "Memory: " + d.SIZE
                    )
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
            });
```

Comment: You just need to add a button to the HTML.

Comment: @Lars Lotthoff As you told  div .html('<select > <option>Action</option>' + // The first <a> tag
         +
        "</select>" +                          // closing </select> tag
        "<br/>"  
            
            )
but on mouseover  it only shows the drop down i am not able to select items from dropdown .how to overcome this . how can i also add the contextmenu their?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tooltip doesn't respond to mouse events (`pointer-events: none;` in the CSS).  This is done to avoid triggering the mouseout event on the node as soon as the tooltip appears above it.  (Normally, the element on top would capture the mouse event, by turning off pointer-events the mouse movements are passed through to the elements underneath).

If you want the tooltip to be interactive, with buttons or links, you'll need to remove that CSS line and figure out a different way of closing/hiding the tooltip.  For example, you could hide the tooltip when the tooltip `<div>` is moused-out, or you could add a dedicated close button on the tooltip.